# Change input data axisx and axisy to arrays of axisx or arrays of axisy for Stacked Bar flot chart

Tags: javascript, charts, smarty, flot

How to change input data axisx and axisy to arrays of axisx or arrays of axisy, from input data [x1,x1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3] to [x1,x2,x3] and [y1,y2,y3]. It is not related to trick at axisy or axisx.

Pls look at input data for Line chart. Its data for axisy is u=[100,35,35,30,105,40,35,30,40,20,15].

```
   function d(k) {
    var n = [];
    for(var e = 0; e <= 10; e += 1) {
        n.push([e, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)])
    }
    var m = [];
    for(var e = 0; e <= 10; e += 1) {
        m.push([e, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)])
    }
    var j = [];
    for(var e = 0; e <= 10; e += 1) {
        j.push([e, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)])
    }
    var l = {
        series: {
            stack: true,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.4
            }
        },
        grid: {
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    };
    a.plot(k, [{
        data: n,
        color: "#E15656"
    }, {
        data: m,
        color: "#A6D037"
    }, {
        data: j,
        color: "#61A5E4"
    }], l)
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/62/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify details (specifically, the `ticks` to be used) for the `yaxis` in your `options` object (`l`):

```
    var l = {
            series: {
                stack: true,
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.4
                }
            },
            grid: {
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            yaxis:{ 
                ticks: [1,3,17,23,35,43] //replace with the array of your dreams
            }
        };
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/65/).

**Edit** (I'm new to answering/commenting, didn't know comment edits had a time limit):

Ok, so it turns out the question is very different from my initial interpretation. My new interpretation is that Alouty would like to use a pair of arrays for a single set of data: one which contains the array of x-values (`[x1,x2,x3,...]`), and one which contains the y-values  (`[y1,y2,y3,...]`).

In final call to `.plot()`, the data object of each series must be of the form `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]`.

While the array `u` is not created in this form (see below), it is translated into an array of coordinate pairs (with timeseries values as the x-value in each pair) before being used as data:

```
var u = [100, 35, 35, 30, 105, 40, 35, 30, 40, 20, 15];
var j = [];
for (var o = 0; o < u.length; o++) {
    j.push([new Date(2012, 5, o + 1), u[o]]);
}
var n = [{
    data: j,
    label: "Sales",
    color: "#E15656"},...
```

You would not be able to use `u` directly as data. You would need to blend your x and y arrays into a single array of coordinate pairs, as is done in the existing code.

Comment: Sorry for making you confused. I would like to change the input data for var n,var m,var j from [[x1,y1],[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]] to axisx - [x1,0,4,8,9] and axisy - [y1,3,8,5,13] just like the existing Line Chart. My input data is in array of axisx or array of axisy but not pair of [x1,y1]. Since the Line chart can do that stacked chart also can do that although I couldn't find it on google and SOF...

Comment: In final call to `.plot()`, the data object of each series must be of the form `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]`.

Even though the array `u` is not in the form, it is translated into coordinate pairs before being used as data:
    for (var o = 0; o < u.length; o++) {
        j.push([new Date(2012, 5, o + 1), u[o]]);